# Proving outer regularity of an inner regular finite Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups, outer-measure, hausdorff-measure, borel-sets

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $(X,\mathcal{B}_X)$. Suppose that $\mu$ is inner regular on open sets and that for all $A \in \mathcal{B}_X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists compact $K \subset A$ such that \begin{align*} B \in \mathcal{B}_X \text{ with } K \subset &B \subset A \implies |\mu(A)-\mu(B)|< \varepsilon \end{align*} Prove that $\mu$ is outer regular on all Borel sets.

---

I'm really stuck here. Is this a matter of using inner regularity on the open sets and taking complements? Or do I just hack through as if I didn't know that $\mu$ was inner regular on open sets?

Any help would be great! :)

Comment: Where did $K$ come from?

Comment: right sorry edited now

Comment: @Thompson any ideas on outer regularity?

Comment: When you say "Is this a matter of using inner regularity..." etc.... Have you tried to make this argument work?

Comment: Well I don't know how to get it off the ground. I know that if I could write any Borel set as a complement of a closed set, then I could use inner regularity on the complement and then I'd be fine. Any ideas?